# Map function in modern c++

Tags: c++

I have this working map function and I'm wondering if I can improve anything. Should I prefer templates instead of auto in this case?

```
auto map = [](auto items, auto fun) {
    vector<decltype(fun(items[0]))> result;

    for (auto item : items) {
        result.push_back(fun(item));
    }

    return result;
};
```

Comment: What's the context? What kind of data will it be used on? What version of C++ are you using? Please read the [help/on-topic] and [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915).

Comment: @Mast There's no context, this function can live in isolation - it's a simple map function I'm writing for educational purpose. It will be used on anything that's iterable as the code states. I'm targeting modern versions of c++ as the title and the code states.

Comment: @salamandra You should take (const) iterators to beginning and end as arguments then. No need to pass the whole container, especially not by value.

Answer (score 2):

I think one thing that you could do is to call `result.reserve(items.size())` (as long as you expect that items can be queried for `size()`) just after you declare it. That would prevent the vector from allocating new space each time new element is added and/or being copied from time to time as the elements are being added to it, which may result in increased performance, especially when items contains a lot of elements and/or of large size.

It's possible that compiler optimizations would do the same to you, but it won't hurt if you put it anyway just in case. Besides, optimizations might be turned off in debug mode.

Also, since you don't modify `items`, it's better to make it `const auto&` for the sake of [const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness) and pass it by reference to avoid unnecessary copying as @Deduplicator has pointed out. The same goes for `item` in the range loop if `fun` is not to modify it.

Comment: That would work for most ranges, and be a useful optimization, but not all can actually be queried for their `.size()`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, didn't know that. Can you give an example of a situation when a std::vector can't be queried for its size? What happens then if you call this function?

Comment: I said range, not `std::vector`. A `std::vector` is a range, but not the other way around. It might only provide `begin()` and `end()`,

Comment: Right, I have missread that. Everything's clear then - thanks for pointing that out. I've udated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your lambda is abominable:

1. You forgot to `std::decay_t` the return-type of `fun()`.
2. You are passing the container `items` by value. That works if it's actually a view, but is otherwise unconscionably inefficient. Not to mention might be impossible or outright wrong.

Comment: "abominable" is a harsh word :)

Comment: Sure, but sometimes hyperbole is fun.